# Getting average of rows in dataframe greater than or equal to zero

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get the average value of a row in a dataframe where I only use values greater than or equal to zero.

For example:
if my dataframe looked like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3,4,5], [4,5,6],[4,-10,6]])
    3   4   5
    4   5   6
    4   -10 6
```

currently if I get the average of the row I write :

```
df['mean'] = df.mean(axis = 1)
```

and get:

```
3   4   5   4
4   5   6   5
4   -10 6   0
```

I would like to get a dataframe that only used values greater than zero to computer the average.  I would like a dataframe that looked like:

```
3   4   5   4
4   5   6   5
4   -10 6   5
```

In the above example -10 is excluded in the average.  Is there a command that excludes the -10?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `df[df > 0]` to query the data frame before calculating the average; `df[df > 0]` returns a data frame where cells smaller or equal to zero will be replaced with `NaN` and get ignored when calculating the `mean`:

```
df[df > 0].mean(1)

#0    4.0
#1    5.0
#2    5.0
#dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

Not nearly as succinct as @Psidom.  But if you wanted to use `numpy` and get some added quickness.

```
v0 = df.values
v1 = np.where(v0 > 0, v0, np.nan)
v2 = np.nanmean(v1, axis=1)
df.assign(Mean=v2)

   0   1  2  Mean
0  3   4  5   4.0
1  4   5  6   5.0
2  4 -10  6   5.0
```

**Timing**
*small data*

```
%timeit df.assign(Mean=df[df > 0].mean(1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.71 ms per loop

%%timeit
v0 = df.values
v1 = np.where(v0 > 0, v0, np.nan)
v2 = np.nanmean(v1, axis=1)
df.assign(Mean=v2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 407 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thank you!!
I hope there is a time when my data sets are so large I have to be concerned about computational time.  Your answer made me feel cool.

Comment: @getaglow whenever I can evoke an emotion such as `'cool'`, I count that as a win!  Glad I could help.